# eBay API ReviseInventoryStatus request returns 'Unsupported ListingType' error when updating quantity and price

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I want to update the quantity and price on eBay using their **[ReviseInventoryStatus](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseInventoryStatus.html)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>MY_AUTH_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <InventoryStatus>
        <ItemID>110150500384</ItemID>
        <StartPrice>2.00</StartPrice>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </InventoryStatus>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest> ​
```

But when I try to run above code it gives me following output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2014-09-22T07:25:15.340Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Unsupported ListingType.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Valid Listing type for fixedprice apis are FixedPriceItem and StoresFixedPrice.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>21916286</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>891</Version>
    <Build>E891_UNI_API5_17051033_R1</Build>
</ReviseInventoryStatusResponse> ​
```

**Error :** `Valid Listing type for fixedprice apis are FixedPriceItem and StoresFixedPrice.`

How to solve this issue so that I can update quantity and price of my item ?

Please help me on this. Is I am doing anything wrong ? Guide me on this

Answer (score 1):

From your XML feed it looks like you are trying to update price and quantity for a product which is on auction rather than fixed priced. And the link [ReviseInventoryStatus][1]

[1]: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseInventoryStatus.html also says that "Enables a seller to change the price and quantity of a currently- active, fixed-price listing" so I don't think you can use this API call to change quantity and price for product on auction.

Try using ReviseItem call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<Item ComplexType="ItemType">
<ItemID>$itemid</ItemID>
<StartPrice currencyID="INR/GBP/USD/EUR3">2.00</StartPrice>
<Quantity>2</Quantity>
</Item>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<Version>837</Version>
</ReviseItemRequest>​
```